# How to speed up python loop

Tags: python, performance, nested-loops

I had a look at several dicussions on several sites and none of them gave me a solution.
This piece of code takes more than 5 seconds to run :

```
for i in xrange(100000000):
  pass
```

I'm working on an integer optimization problem and I have to use an  *O(n log n)* algorithm **edit : an O(n²/4) algorithm, where n stands for all the matrix' items, ie, in the following code, n * m = 10000. So, for a matrix 100 * 100 with 10000 elements, it will result in nearly 25000000 iterations ...**.
Its code can be summed up like this :

```
m = 100
n = 100
for i in xrange(m):
  for j in xrange(n):
    for i2 in xrange(i + 1, m):
      for j2 in xrange(j + 1, n):
        if myarray[i][j] == myarray[i2][j2] and myarray[i2][j] == myarray[i][j2]:
          return [i, j], [i2, j2]
```

Should I give up with Python and go back to Java or to C ?

I work with Python 2.7 and Psyco isn't available. PyPy doesn't support Tkinter out of the box and I'm using Tkinter.

So, would they improve the looping speed ? Are there other solutions ?

Comment: did you try to implement this with numpy arrays if that is possible ?

Comment: PyPy certainly speeds such loops up.

Comment: You can speed up your loops all you want, the code above is not O(n log n).

Comment: And pypy would speed things up, but by a factor of 4-5. Such a loop should take less than 0.5 sec on a decent computer when written in c.

Comment: It looks like this algorithm is n^2*m^2, and there's not a lot of optimization you can do to speed it up in a particular language.  You would benefit *far more* from reexamining your algorithm and seeing if there are any unnecessary iterations.

Comment: Yes but as Paul McGuire figured out, I'm looking for rectangles and I can't do less iteration... This algorithm would run faster in C or in Java because a loop iteration doesn't need so many CPU cycles like in Python ...

Comment: Just to be clear what your asking: Your algorithm is fix and you won't change it, and want to know which language suites your task best? Or do you want a optimized version of your algorithm?

Comment: It is fixed and I want to know how to make it faster in Python. I starded using cython this afternoon. It is part of a bigger program but the rest of the code doesn't need optimization.

Answer (score 17):

Not the prettiest coding style, but desperate times call for desperate coding.  Try turning your nested nested loops into one big generator expression:

```
try:
    i,j,i2,j2 = ((i,j,i2,j2)
        for i in xrange(m)
          for j in xrange(n)
            for i2 in xrange(i + 1, m)
              for j2 in xrange(j + 1, n)
                if myarray[i][j] == myarray[i2][j2] and 
                    myarray[i2][j] == myarray[i][j2]).next()
    return [i,j],[i2,j2]
except StopIteration:
    return None
```

Updated to use builtins `next` and `product`, and Py3 `range` instead of `xrange`:

```
from itertools import product
match = next(((i,j,i2,j2)
    for i, j in product(range(m), range(n))
        for i2, j2 in product(range(i+1, m), range(j+1, n))
            if myarray[i][j] == myarray[i2][j2] and 
                myarray[i2][j] == myarray[i][j2]), None)
if match is not None:
    i,j,i2,j2 = match
    return [i,j],[i2,j2]
else:
    return None
```

Comment: It didn't improve the speed but nice expression anyway.

Comment: Can't upvote at the moment, need 5 more reputation points : /

Answer (score 13):

You can still use the python notation, and have the speed of C, using the [Cython](http://cython.org/) project.
A first step would be to convert the loop in C loop: it's automatically done by typing all the variables used in the loop:

```
cdef int m = 100
cdef int n = 100
cdef int i, j, i2, j2
for i in xrange(m):
  for j in xrange(n):
    for i2 in xrange(i + 1, m):
      for j2 in xrange(j + 1, n):
```

For The next part, it would be even better if that myarray would be pure C array, then no rich python comparaison nor array access. With your python array, you can remove the rich comparaison by doing native comparaison (if you have double in your array):

```
        cdef double a, b, c, d
        a = myarray[i][j]
        b = myarray[i2][j2]
        c = myarray[i2][j]
        d = myarray[i][j2]

        if a == b and c == d:
          return [i, j], [i2, j2]
```

You can see how optimization are going by running `cython -a yourfile.pyx`, then open the `yourfile.html` generate. You'll see how Cython have optimized your code, and removed Python overhead.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try cython cause I need a big boost of speed.

Comment: This page detail the benefits from cython with a problem similar to the one I'm dealing with : http://www.korokithakis.net/posts/optimizing-python-with-cython/

Comment: I started using cython and numpy for the arrays. Loops are really faster. But I got a problem : I have function calls that slow down the loops, so I've got a lot of work to do with cython.

Comment: function call in python are expensive. Learn Cython more, you'll see how awesome it is :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to tell you, but it's not a matter of optimization. No matter which language or implementation you choose, this algorithm is not `O(n*log n)` in the worst- and average case. You might want to read up on [how the Big-O notation works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/916657) and develop a better algorithm.

Comment: Ok it is O(n²/4), not O(n log n), but there is no other algorithms and this is an optimisation problem (see edit in the main post for details).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the generator expr didn't work. Here is a different scheme that first tallies all like values, and then looks for rectangular groups:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations
def f3(myarray):
    tally = defaultdict(list)
    for i,row in enumerate(myarray):
        for j,n in enumerate(row):
            tally[n].append((i,j))

    # look for rectangular quads in each list
    for k,v in tally.items():
        for quad in permutations(v,4):
            # sort quad so that we can get rectangle corners 
            quad = sorted(quad)
            (i1,j1),(i2,j2) = quad[0], quad[-1]

            # slice out opposite corners to see if we have a rectangle
            others = quad[1:3]

            if [(i1,j2),(i2,j1)] == others:
                return [i1,j1],[i2,j2]
```

Comment: thanks, I tryed it and learned some new things about Python syntax, but it didn't run faster than the other things.

Comment: If you have a sparse array, and you only want matching values that are nonzero, then you can skip all of the permutation testing of the zero cells by preceding the `for quad in permutations(v,4):` statement with `if k == 0: continue`.

Answer (score 1):

I looked several times across your code and if i get it right, your marking your rectangles with two different corner-markers. I'm sorry if my answer is more a comment to clarify your position then a really answer.

**Answer-Part:**:
If your looking for an appropriate algorithm, consider a scan-line algorithm. I found an example [here @SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932031/1107807) for a "biggest rectangle solution".

My Question to you is, what are you really looking for?

1. best way to solve the for-loop dilemma
2. best language for your algorithm
3. a faster algorithm to find rectangles

I must also point out, that Paul's and your solution produce different results, because Pauls assumes corners are marked by same values and you assume, that corners are marked through two different values!

I took the time and liberty to illustrate it with a ugly c&p script:
It compares both algorithm by creating a 2D-field and fills it with
string.lowercase chars and turns the corners to uppercase-chars.

```
from random import choice
from string import lowercase
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations
from copy import deepcopy

m,n = 20, 20
myarray = [[choice(lowercase) for x in xrange(m)] for y in xrange(n)]

def markcorners(i,j,i2,j2):
    myarray[i][j] = myarray[i][j].upper()
    myarray[i2][j] = myarray[i2][j].upper()
    myarray[i2][j2] = myarray[i2][j2].upper()
    myarray[i][j2] = myarray[i][j2].upper()

def printrect():
    for row in myarray:
        print ''.join(row)
    print '*'*m

def paul_algo():
    tally = defaultdict(list)
    for i,row in enumerate(myarray):
        for j,n in enumerate(row):
            tally[n].append((i,j))

    # look for rectangular quads in each list
    for k,v in tally.items():
        for quad in permutations(v,4):
            # sort quad so that we can get rectangle corners 
            quad = sorted(quad)
            (i1,j1),(i2,j2) = quad[0], quad[-1]

            # slice out opposite corners to see if we have a rectangle
            others = quad[1:3]

            if [(i1,j2),(i2,j1)] == others:
                markcorners(i1,j1,i2,j2)

def xavier_algo():   
    for i in xrange(m):
        for j in xrange(n):
            for i2 in xrange(i + 1, m):
                for j2 in xrange(j + 1, n):
                    if myarray[i][j] == myarray[i2][j2] and myarray[i2][j] == myarray[i][j2]:
                        markcorners(i,j,i2,j2)

savearray = deepcopy(myarray)
printrect()

xavier_algo()
printrect()

myarray = deepcopy(savearray)
paul_algo()
printrect()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I need the opposite corners values to be different. A better algorithm would be nice. I will have a look at the one you point out tommorow. Got to sleep now cause it's kinda late here.

Comment: I had a look at the algo you suggested. Well thought, but it doesn't fit my needs which are particular. I don't need to find the biggest rectangle but I have to find all of them with  opposite corners that got the same value. It is used in a neighbourhood function in a tabu search for a discrete optimization problem.