# I need to perform an "expensive" loop on a table with millions of rows. What technology (programming language or something else) should I use?

Tags: python, performance, loops

This question is a follow up to this one: [How to the increase performance of a Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744864/how-to-the-increase-performance-of-a-python-loop).

Basically I have a script that takes as inputs a few csv files and after some data manipulation it outputs 2 csv files. In this script there is a loop on a table with ~14 million rows whose objective is to create another table with the same number of rows. I am working with Python on this project but the loop is just too slow (I know this because I used the tqdm package to measure speed).

So I’m looking for suggestions on what I should use in order to achieve my objective. Ideally the technology is free and it doesn’t take long for to learn it. I already got a few suggestions from other people: Cython and Power BI. The last one is paid and the first one seems complicated but I am willing to learn if indeed it is useful.

If more details are necessary just ask. Thanks.

Comment: One important part: is each operation on a row local? In other words: can you do them one by one or do you need to know all input rows before you can produce the first output row?

Comment: No, they are not local.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/index.html). Vaex can help you to process your data much much faster. You should first convert your csv file to hdf5 format using `vaex` library. csv files are very slow for read/write.

Vaex will do the multiprocessing for your operations.

Also check if you can vectorize your computation (probably you can). I glansed at your code. Try to avoid using `list` instead use numpy arrays if you can.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to stay with python I would probably recommend using the multiprocessing module. Corey Schafer has a good tutorial on how it works [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso).

Multiprocessing is a bit like threading however uses multiple interpreters to complete the main task unlike the threading module which switches through each thread to execute a line of code independently.

Divide up the work with however many cores you have on your CPU with this:

```
import os
cores = os.cpu_count()
```

This should speed up the work load by dividing up the work across your entire computer.

Answer (score 2):

14 million rows is very achievable with python, but you can't do it with inefficient looping methods. I had a glance at the code you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744864/how-to-the-increase-performance-of-a-python-loop), and saw that you're using `iterrows()`. `iterrows()` is fine for small dataframes, but it is (as you know) painfully slow when used on dataframes the size of yours. Instead, I suggest you start by looking into the `apply()` method (see docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)). That should get you up to speed!

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion but I have a problem. I do df.apply(..., axis = 0), where df is a DataFrame with 2 columns. The apply method applies the given function to each row, each column at a time. However, I need to be able to access values from the 2 columns of each row to do what I want.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Should be possible! You should be able to find examples in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column